# Cannot access bios settings on AMI

Tags: bios

I cannot get into bios settings, whenever I press del it just goes to boot select screen. It is AMI BIOS.

**EDIT**
It is a new motherboard, P4M800 pro-m_V2.0, with Vista. It is only recognising 1gb of ram  but there are 2x 1gb sticks in it.

CPU-Z (CPU-Z is a freeware that gathers information on some of the main devices of your system) shows both sticks.

Comment: More detail would be helpful. What brand and model of computer is this? Did it work previously?

Comment: it is a new motherboard, p4m800 pro-m_V2.0, i recently put vista on it, and it is only recognising 1gb of ram , but there are 2x 1gb sticks in it, and tried cpu-z and that shows both sticks, so i want to av a look at the bios settings but i cant get in it just goes to boot select screen , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Often there is another key you need to press instead of <kbd>del</kbd>. You should see a message telling you which key when the computer is first switched on. Try <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>. Also, some laptops, Lenovo ThinkPads for example, have a special key for this.

You should search for your specific hardware. The motherboard model if you are using a desktop, or the laptop model if a laptop.

Comment: it does say press del but just goes to windows boot select page

Comment: Try pressing del repeatedly, starting as soon as you reboot the computer. Modern systems have very short POST times and it is sometimes hard to do it on time.

Comment: yer i can see why that would be the case, i was waiting for it to flash up and then pressing del, i will give that a go and get back to you thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the User Manual, downloaded from the [ECS web site](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=673&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=16&LanID=9), either <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> are used to enter BIOS setup. Try <kbd>F1</kbd>.

If neither work, you may have a defective motherboard and will need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @ryanraz The detail described is from page 28 of the manual

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have the BIOS protect jumper plugged in? Open the [manual](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=673&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=16&LanID=9) on page 9.